# Display Results of Current Form Submission on a New Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have this form and I want to display the results of the form entry on another page when it is submitted. The values all go into a table in the database. I don't know how to make all the values from the resulting record display on that new page.

This is the form:

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hestonw0355");
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hestonw0355", "1Password!", "hestonw0355"); //for the school server
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sungr_RobW", "O+N7?Pa%Go*T&", "sungraff_hestonw0355"); //for dailyrazor.com

?>
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/index.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f9ecf2;">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 grad" style="background-color:  ; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;  border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #4d004d; border-bottom-width: 1px; padding-left: 0px;"><!-- begin middle column -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
<div style='width: 85%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
            <br><br><br>
            <form action="check-checkout.php" method="post" name="checkout">
                <table width="100%" border="0" class="responsive">
                <tr><td><input name="order_date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>" ></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="30%" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">First Name:</b5></td>
                        <td><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_first_name" id="order_first_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50"  required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="30%" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Last Name:</b5></td>
                        <td><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_last_name" id="order_last_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="40"  required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="30%" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Address:</b5></td>
                        <td><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_address" id="order_address" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255"  required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="30%" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">City:</b5></td>
                        <td><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_city" id="order_city" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50"  required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="30%" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Select State:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><select name="order_state" id="order_state" >
                                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                                <option value="CA">California</option>
                                                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                                                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                            </select></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Zip Code:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_zip" id="order_zip" type="text" size="50" maxlength="10" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Phone:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_tel" id="order_tel" type="text" size="50" maxlength="25" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Email Address:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="order_email" type="email" id="order_email" size="50" maxlength="100" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Select Card Type:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px; font-size: 24pt; color: #4d004d"><p><b5>
                        <img src="img/cc-mastercard.png" width="75" height="49" alt=""/><input type="radio" name="cc_type" value="Mastercard">
                        <img src="img/cc-visa.png" width="75" height="49" alt=""/><input type="radio" name="cc_type" value="Visa">
                        <img src="img/cc-american-express.png" width="75" height="49" alt=""/><input type="radio" name="cc_type" value="American Express">
                        <img src="img/cc-paypal.png" width="75" height="49" alt=""/><input type="radio" name="cc_type" value="PayPal">
                        </b5></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Card Number:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="cc_number" type="integer" id="cc_number" size="50" maxlength="16" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">Expiration:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="cc_expmonth" type="integer" id="cc_expmonth" size="2" maxlength="2" required="required" /><span Style='font-size: 18pt; color: #4d004d'><b3>&nbsp/&nbsp</span></b3><input name="cc_expyear" type="integer" id="cc_expyear" size="2" maxlength="2" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><b5 style="text-align: right; line-height: 80%; font-size: 16pt; color: black;">CVC Code:</b5></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b3 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="cc_cvc" type="integer" id="cc_cvc" size="3" maxlength="3" required="required" /></b3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"></td>
                        <td style=" padding-top: 5px;"><b5 style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" /></b5></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
                </form>
                </div>
            <br><br><br> 
<!-- InstanceEndEditable --> 
      </div><!-- end middle column -->

</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

There's a lot of other things in there but this is the form... and... 
This is the processing page for the form (check-checkout.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

//connect to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hestonw0355");
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hestonw0355", "1Password!", "hestonw0355") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); //for the school server
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sungr_RobW", "O+N7?Pa%Go*T&", "sungraff_hestonw0355") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); //for dailyrazor.com
?>
<?php
$datetime = $_POST['order_date'];
$fname = $_POST['order_first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['order_last_name'];
$address = $_POST['order_address'];
$city = $_POST['order_city'];
$state = $_POST['order_state'];
$zip = $_POST['order_zip'];
$phone = $_POST['order_tel'];
$email = $_POST['order_email'];
$cardtype = $_POST['cc_type'];
$cardnumber = $_POST['cc_number'];
$cardmonth = $_POST['cc_expmonth'];
$cardyear = $_POST['cc_expyear'];
$cardcvc = $_POST['cc_cvc'];

$mysqli = "INSERT INTO store_orders (`order_date`, `order_first_name`, `order_last_name`, `order_address`, `order_city`, `order_state`, `order_zip`, `order_tel`, `order_email`, `cc_type`, `cc_number`, `cc_expmonth`, `cc_expyear`, `cc_cvc` ) VALUES ('".$datetime."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$address."','".$city."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$cardtype."','".$cardnumber."','".$cardmonth."','".$cardyear."','".$cardcvc."')";

if (isset($_POST['checkout'])) {
    header ("location:checkout-view.php");
}
    else { header("location:checkout-form.php"); }

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

This is the table where the form inputs go:

```
    CREATE TABLE `store_orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `order_first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_state` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `order_tel` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `order_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cc_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cc_number` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `cc_expmonth` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cc_expyear` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cc_cvc` int(3) NOT NULL
)
```

This is the page where I want to display the results of the form submission. I already have that page displaying the contents of their shopping cart with totals for the prices of the items they selected added into it. Once I get the form results to show up under that, I will have a page that displays all the user's selections, the prices and totals of prices, and everything they entered into the checkout form. I'm not concerned with all that going into a final purchase process or any security right now, just getting all that to display on a page for the user.

This is the page I need to put it in (checkout_view.php) I al:

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hestonw0355");
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hestonw0355", "1Password!", "hestonw0355"); //for the school server
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sungr_RobW", "O+N7?Pa%Go*T&", "sungraff_hestonw0355") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); //for dailyrazor.com
$sub_total = 0;
$display_block = "<h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>";

//check for cart items based on user session id
$get_cart_sql = "SELECT st.id, si.item_title, si.item_price,
                st.sel_item_qty, st.sel_item_size, st.sel_item_color FROM
                store_shoppertrack AS st LEFT JOIN store_items AS si ON
                si.id = st.sel_item_id WHERE session_id =
                '".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']."'";
$get_cart_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_cart_sql)
                or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));



if (mysqli_num_rows($get_cart_res) < 1) {
    //print message
    $display_block .= "<p>You have no items in your cart.
    Please <a href=\"seestore.php\">continue to shop</a>!</p>";
} else {

    while ($cart_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_res)) {
        $id = $cart_info['id'];
        $item_title = stripslashes($cart_info['item_title']);
        $item_price = $cart_info['item_price'];
        $item_qty = $cart_info['sel_item_qty'];
        $item_color = $cart_info['sel_item_color'];
        $item_size = $cart_info['sel_item_size'];
        $total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $item_price * $item_qty);
        $sub_total += $total_price;
        $grand_total = sprintf("%.02f", $sub_total * .06 + $sub_total);
        $ship_count += $item_qty;
        $total_ship = sprintf("%.02f", $ship_count * 3.5 + $grand_total);

    //get info and build cart display
    $display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT

    <table width='100%'>
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$item_title <br></td>
    <td>$item_size <br></td>
    <td>$item_color <br></td>
    <td>\$ $item_price <br></td>
    <td>$item_qty <br></td>
    <td>\$ $total_price</td>
    <td><a href="removefromcart.php?id=$id">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='5'></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>Subtotal: </td>
    <td>\$ $sub_total </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='4'></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>Add 6% Sales Tax</td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>Total with tax.: </td>
    <td>\$ $grand_total </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='4'></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>Add $3.50 per item for shipping.</td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>Grand Total: </td>
    <td>\$ $total_ship </td>
    </tr>
END_OF_TEXT;
    }
    $display_block .= "</table>";
}
//free result
mysqli_free_result($get_cart_res);

//close connection to MySQL
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/index.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<style>
table {
        border: 2px solid #4d004d;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    th {
    border: 1px solid #4d004d;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #d9b3ff;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;  font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
    td {
    border: 1px solid #4d004d;
    padding: 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f5ecfe;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;  font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f9ecf2;">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 grad" style="background-color:  ; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;  border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #4d004d; border-bottom-width: 1px; padding-left: 0px;"><!-- begin middle column -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
            <br><br><?php echo $display_block; ?><br><br><br> 
<!-- InstanceEndEditable --> 
      </div><!-- end middle column -->
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

There is a lot of other stuff on the page but not needed to show here. I would love to add the display code for the form results up there in the existing PHP like the item selections then put another (echo $display_block;) in the html, but I don't care... any way I can get that current record that was just submitted into the page for display would make my day!!!! I'm really new to this stuff --but learning-- so I just need some help. The solution to this would probably be kindergarten stuff to most of you. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing correctly...

What you need to do is store the ID that was inserted in the database and send that back to the checkout_view.php page, you can then search by that ID on that page.

So on "check-checkout.php" you would do something like this:

Grab the ID using (if I understand how you're using mysql correctly)

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
```

See more about that here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

And then:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkout'])) {
    header ("location:checkout-view.php?id=$last_id");
}
    else { header("location:checkout-form.php"); }
```

You then adjust your sql query to grab the row from the ID in the URL using:

```
$_GET['id']
```

Really basic stuff, but you will get the hand of it :)

Ps. I hope those aren't real passwords ;)